# Complex integral $j=n$ and $j\neq n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have the following integral:
$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{dB(a,r)} (z-a)^{j-n-1} dx$. Why kan we say that this is equal to 0 if $j\neq n$ and equal to 1 if $j=n$?
If $j=n$ than we have: $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{dB(a,r)} \frac{1}{z-a} dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}*2\pi i=1$. Can anyone help me out with the case $j\neq n$?

Comment: Have you tried a parametrization of the circle, like $z=a+re^{it}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a$ is the centre of the disk over whose boundary is integrated, an explicit parametrisation leads to an easily evaluated integral.

On a higher level, for $k \neq -1$, the function $f_k \colon z \mapsto (z-a)^k$ has a primitive on $\mathbb{C}$ (or on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{a\}$, for $k < 0$), namely $F_k \colon z \mapsto \frac{1}{k+1}(z-a)^{k+1}$, and the fundamental theorem of calculus says that then

$$\int_\gamma f_k(z)\,dz = F_k(v) - F_k(u)$$

for *every* path (that is regular enough to define the integral) $\gamma$ whose start point is $u$ and whose endpoint is $v$. For a closed path like $\partial B(a,r)$, endpoint and start point coincide, $u = v$, hence the integral is $0$.

Note: $f \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ has a primitive if and only if $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$ for every closed path $\gamma$ in $U$.